# How to evaluate an Earth system model in light of the spatial variability of observed variables?

Tags: correlation, simulation, model-evaluation, r-squared

**Context**

My effort is to evaluate the performance of a physics-based numerical model to determine how well it simulates different state variables of a soil column (1D inside the model). The temporal scale of the evaluation is daily, and the spatial scale of the model output is point-scale.

One of the evaluation metrics I use is the coefficient of determination, $R^2$ (the square of Pearson $r$).

**Question**

To judge the model performance in simulating soil moisture dynamics at a certain depth and for a given period, how can I incorporate the given information: the R$^2$ between two adjacent soil moisture at the depth of interest is 0.2 (Figure a)? This could be an indication of high spatial variability of soil moisture in the natural system.

- The R$^2$ between the model and average of the sensor measurements is 0.23 (Figure b). What are the different ways to judge the model performance?

[image: Scatter Plot]

I tend to think of the low R$^2$ (0.2) between the sensors as a low benchmark. Therefore, I will not deem the model as an inadequate one if the R$^2$ between the model and observations is not higher than 0.2.

Comment: Your reasoning is unconvincing because it conflates "acceptability," which is a matter of why you are doing this calculation, with spatial variability.  Indeed, it is possible for a model to achieve arbitrarily high $R^2$ even when spatial variability is arbitrarily large.  It would be difficult for anyone to supply an objective answer until you can say more about your situation.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. I try to improve the question.

Comment: The *negative* association between simulations and observations suggests the simulations are terrible -- even worse than a model that merely returns the average observation each time!  Until you fix this up and achieve a model that is at least somewhat reasonable, these statistical issues are of little relevance.